# c# SMTP auth send problem Syntax error in parameter or arguments

Tags: .net, authentication, smtp

I have a method in c# that sends email. Works fine and has been working fine for two years.

I ran into a problem with one SMTP server. I viewed TCP conversation using SmartSniff and found a problematic handshake:

after command

> AUTH login dGJp

I get an error saying

> 501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments

On the other hand, when I send mail from outlook with the same account the above command is split in two parts:

> AUTH LOGIN
>
> 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
>
> dGJp

As you can see, when sending from outlook, client pauses before sending username and server responses asking "Username:" (VXNlcm5hbWU6)
No error happend after that line. Then the server asks for password and replys with **235 Authentication successful**

Has anyone ran into this problem?

I tried with different mail servers and everything works OK when authenticating on one line (first example). For some reason this SMTP server does not like it.

Any ideas?

Comment: what has changed in your program or servers or infrastructure recently? Since it used to work for two years something should have changed recently to break it.

Answer (score 1):

It does not really help you, but AUTH LOGIN is deprecated, non-standard method, it does not have a formal specification. There is an informational RFC attempting to document it for historical purposes and a Microsoft specification. These  contradict each other. .Net seems to be implementing it in the Microsoft way, while the server you encountered implements it otherwise. (Which server software does it use by the way?) If possible use the AUTH PLAIN method which is standard.